# Retrieve a document query with Email firebase firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Code:

[image: Here is the server side code I've written. Please take a look]

At line number 57 I created a route to get the data according to user's email.
But I'm unable to get the specific data that this user added to the database. The response I'm getting is looking like this. I'm stuck here although I followed the instruction that is provided in the firebase firestore documentation.

```js
QuerySnapshot {
  _firestore: Firestore {
    _authCredentials: FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider {
      authProvider: [Provider],
      currentUser: [User],
      tokenCounter: 0,
      forceRefresh: false,
      auth: null,
      tokenListener: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _appCheckCredentials: FirebaseAppCheckTokenProvider {
      appCheckProvider: [Provider],
      forceRefresh: false,
      appCheck: null,
      tokenListener: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    type: 'firestore',
    _persistenceKey: '[DEFAULT]',
    _settings: FirestoreSettingsImpl {
      host: 'firestore.googleapis.com',
      ssl: true,
      credentials: undefined,
      ignoreUndefinedProperties: false,
      cacheSizeBytes: 41943040,
      experimentalForceLongPolling: false,
      experimentalAutoDetectLongPolling: false,
      useFetchStreams: true
    },
    _settingsFrozen: true,
    _app: FirebaseAppImpl {
      _isDeleted: false,
      _options: [Object],
      _config: [Object],
      _name: '[DEFAULT]',
      _automaticDataCollectionEnabled: false,
      _container: [ComponentContainer]
    },
    _databaseId: DatabaseId { projectId: 'parlour-1bcf7', database: '(default)' },
    _queue: AsyncQueueImpl {
      tail: [Promise],
      retryableOps: [],
      _isShuttingDown: false,
      delayedOperations: [Array],
      failure: null,
      operationInProgress: true,
      skipNonRestrictedTasks: false,
      timerIdsToSkip: [],
      backoff: [ExponentialBackoff],
      visibilityHandler: [Function (anonymous)]
    },
    _firestoreClient: FirestoreClient {
      authCredentials: [FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider],
      appCheckCredentials: [FirebaseAppCheckTokenProvider],
      asyncQueue: [AsyncQueueImpl],
      databaseInfo: [DatabaseInfo],
      user: [User],
      clientId: 'Hoh8WrPk3BFhkBsirvQx',
      authCredentialListener: [Function (anonymous)],
      appCheckCredentialListener: [Function (anonymous)],
      offlineComponents: [MemoryOfflineComponentProvider],
      onlineComponents: [OnlineComponentProvider]
    }
  },
  _userDataWriter: ExpUserDataWriter {
    firestore: Firestore {
      _authCredentials: [FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider],
      _appCheckCredentials: [FirebaseAppCheckTokenProvider],
      type: 'firestore',
      _persistenceKey: '[DEFAULT]',
      _settings: [FirestoreSettingsImpl],
      _settingsFrozen: true,
      _app: [FirebaseAppImpl],
      _databaseId: [DatabaseId],
      _queue: [AsyncQueueImpl],
      _firestoreClient: [FirestoreClient]
    }
  },
  _snapshot: ViewSnapshot {
    query: QueryImpl {
      path: [ResourcePath],
      collectionGroup: null,
      explicitOrderBy: [],
      filters: [Array],
      limit: null,
      limitType: 'F',
      startAt: null,
      endAt: null,
      memoizedOrderBy: [Array],
      memoizedTarget: [TargetImpl]
    },
    docs: DocumentSet {
      comparator: [Function (anonymous)],
      keyedMap: [SortedMap],
      sortedSet: [SortedMap]
    },
    oldDocs: DocumentSet {
      comparator: [Function (anonymous)],
      keyedMap: [SortedMap],
      sortedSet: [SortedMap]
    },
    docChanges: [],
    mutatedKeys: SortedSet { comparator: [Function: comparator], data: [SortedMap] },
    fromCache: false,
    syncStateChanged: true,
    excludesMetadataChanges: false
  },
  metadata: SnapshotMetadata { hasPendingWrites: false, fromCache: false },
  query: Query {
    converter: null,
    _query: QueryImpl {
      path: [ResourcePath],
      collectionGroup: null,
      explicitOrderBy: [],
      filters: [Array],
      limit: null,
      limitType: 'F',
      startAt: null,
      endAt: null,
      memoizedOrderBy: [Array],
      memoizedTarget: [TargetImpl]
    },
    type: 'query',
    firestore: Firestore {
      _authCredentials: [FirebaseAuthCredentialsProvider],
      _appCheckCredentials: [FirebaseAppCheckTokenProvider],
      type: 'firestore',
      _persistenceKey: '[DEFAULT]',
      _settings: [FirestoreSettingsImpl],
      _settingsFrozen: true,
      _app: [FirebaseAppImpl],
      _databaseId: [DatabaseId],
      _queue: [AsyncQueueImpl],
      _firestoreClient: [FirestoreClient]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of logging the query snapshot itself, try running a loop and adding each documents data in array just like line 50

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Do not post images of code. Post the code I’m markdown instead

Answer (score 0):

Replace lines 64 to 67 with the following snippet

```
for (const doc of querySnapshot.docs) {
    console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data())
}
```